# How to fill inner area between multiple SVG paths?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I work with d3js (v4) and I'd like to fill a specific area defined by multiple paths.

Here is my shape:

[image]

And here is my code:

```js
var width = 400,
  height = 350;

var svg = d3.select('#svgContainer')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('background-color', 'white');

var shape = {
  leftEdge: [],
  topCurve: [],
  supportJunction: [],
  bottomCurve: [],
  centralSupport: [],
  width: 0
};

/* Set path data */
var startX = 200,
  startY = 80,
  centralSupportW = 10,
  centralSupportH = 25;

shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX - centralSupportW,
  y: startY - centralSupportH
});
shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX + centralSupportW,
  y: startY - centralSupportH
});
shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX + centralSupportW,
  y: startY + centralSupportH
});
shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX - centralSupportW,
  y: startY + centralSupportH
});

var shapeW = 80,
  shapeH = 60,
  curve = 40,
  intensity = 6;

shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve,
  y: startY + shapeH,
  id: 1
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve / intensity,
  y: startY + shapeH,
  id: 2
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW,
  y: startY,
  id: 3
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve / intensity,
  y: startY - shapeH,
  id: 4
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve,
  y: startY - shapeH,
  id: 5
});

var topCurveIntensity = 10;
var centralPosition = 5;

shape.topCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[shape.leftEdge.length - 1].x,
  y: shape.leftEdge[shape.leftEdge.length - 1].y,
  id: 6
});
shape.topCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[shape.leftEdge.length - 1].x - topCurveIntensity,
  y: shape.centralSupport[0].y + centralPosition,
  id: 7
});
shape.topCurve.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[0].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[0].y + centralPosition,
  id: 8
});

shape.supportJunction.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[0].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[0].y + centralPosition,
  id: 9
});
shape.supportJunction.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].y - centralPosition,
  id: 10
});

shape.bottomCurve.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].y - centralPosition,
  id: 11
});

shape.bottomCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[0].x - topCurveIntensity,
  y: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].y - centralPosition,
  id: 12
});

shape.bottomCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[0].x,
  y: shape.leftEdge[0].y,
  id: 13
});
/*  */


/* draw paths */
var regularLine = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

var curvedLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBundle)
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

var closedLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

/*
svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.centralSupport)
  .attr('d', closedLine)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');
*/

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.leftEdge)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', '#A0A3A5')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.topCurve)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', '#A0A3A5')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.bottomCurve)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', '#A0A3A5')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.supportJunction)
  .attr('d', regularLine)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', '#A0A3A5')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');

var data = '';
svg.selectAll('path')
  .each(function() {
    data += d3.select(this).attr('d');
  });
svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', data)
  .style('fill', 'lightgray')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', '1px')
  .style('fill-rule', 'evenodd');
/* */
/* draw points used */
svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.leftEdge)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'black');


svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.topCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'blue');

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.bottomCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'red');
/* */

/* draw labels */
svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.leftEdge)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return d.x - 16;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return d.y + 10;
  })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  });

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.topCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return d.y - 8;
  })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .style('fill', 'blue');


svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.supportJunction)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return d.x + 16;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return d.y - 8;
  })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .style('fill', 'purple');

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.bottomCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    return d.x - 16;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return d.y - 8;
  })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .style('fill', 'red');
/* */
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgContainer"></div>
```

*Note: this snippet uses some random values to generate the shape (to reflect what I really need).*

Each path is defined by an array of coordinates. Each of them used different curved or linear lines.

This is the code for a single path:

```
g.append('path')
  .datum(foobar)
  .attr('d', d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle)
    .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function (d) { return d.y; }))
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'purple')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');
```

I tried to concatenate the data of each path but the filling isn't properly done:

```
var data = '';
svg.selectAll('path')
  .each(function () { data += d3.select(this).attr('d'); });
svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', data)
  .style('fill', 'red')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .style('stroke-width', '3px');
```

[image]

Below the shape with all the points used to draw the paths (one color per path).  Some of them are shared between paths (1 13, 5 6, 8 9, 10 11)

[image]

Do you have any idea how I could fill the contain (i. e. inner section) of these paths?

Comment: You'd need to concatenate the path's d attributes into a single path.

Comment: Create a [mcve] if you want any more help.

Comment: @RobertLongson Right, I created a JSFiddle to reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ev4821c6/3/

Answer (score 3):

The idea consists in concatenating sub-path's `d` attributes into one:

Here is the demo:

```js
var width = 400,
    height = 350;

var svg = d3.select('#svgContainer')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .style('background-color', 'white');

var shape = {
  leftEdge: [],
  topCurve: [],
  supportJunction: [],
  bottomCurve: [],
  centralSupport: [],
  width: 0
};

/* Set path data */
var startX = 200,
  startY = 80,
  centralSupportW = 10,
  centralSupportH = 25;

shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX - centralSupportW,
  y: startY - centralSupportH
});
shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX + centralSupportW,
  y: startY - centralSupportH
});
shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX + centralSupportW,
  y: startY + centralSupportH
});
shape.centralSupport.push({
  x: startX - centralSupportW,
  y: startY + centralSupportH
});

var shapeW = 80,
  shapeH = 60,
  curve = 40,
  intensity = 6;

shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve,
  y: startY + shapeH,
  id: 1
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve / intensity,
  y: startY + shapeH,
  id: 2
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW,
  y: startY,
  id: 3
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve / intensity,
  y: startY - shapeH,
  id: 4
});
shape.leftEdge.push({
  x: startX - shapeW + curve,
  y: startY - shapeH,
  id: 5
});

var topCurveIntensity = 10;
var centralPosition = 5;

shape.topCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[shape.leftEdge.length - 1].x,
  y: shape.leftEdge[shape.leftEdge.length - 1].y,
  id: 6
});
shape.topCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[shape.leftEdge.length - 1].x - topCurveIntensity,
  y: shape.centralSupport[0].y + centralPosition,
  id: 7
});
shape.topCurve.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[0].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[0].y + centralPosition,
  id: 8
});

shape.supportJunction.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[0].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[0].y + centralPosition,
  id: 9
});
shape.supportJunction.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].y - centralPosition,
  id: 10
});

shape.bottomCurve.push({
  x: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].x,
  y: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].y - centralPosition,
  id: 11
});

shape.bottomCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[0].x - topCurveIntensity,
  y: shape.centralSupport[shape.centralSupport.length - 1].y - centralPosition,
  id: 12
});

shape.bottomCurve.push({
  x: shape.leftEdge[0].x,
  y: shape.leftEdge[0].y,
  id: 13
});

/* draw paths */
var regularLine = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

var curvedLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBundle)
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

var closedLine = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveLinearClosed)
  .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
  .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.leftEdge)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)
  .attr("id", "left_edge")
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'grey')
  .style('stroke-width', '2px');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.topCurve)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)
  .attr("id", "top_curve")
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'grey')
  .style('stroke-width', '2px');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.bottomCurve)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)
  .attr("id", "bottom_curve")
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'grey')
  .style('stroke-width', '2px');

svg.append('path')
  .datum(shape.supportJunction)
  .attr('d', regularLine)
  .attr("id", "support_junction")
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'grey')
  .style('stroke-width', '1px');

var leftEdge = svg.select("#left_edge")
var topCurve = svg.select("#top_curve");
var supportJunction = svg.select("#support_junction");
var curvedLine = svg.select("#bottom_curve");

// Let's merge all paths together by replacing left edge's d attribute (path)
// with the concatenation of the different sub-paths:
leftEdge
  .attr(
    "d",
    [
      leftEdge.attr("d"),
      topCurve.attr("d").replace("M160,20", ""),
      supportJunction.attr("d"),
      curvedLine.attr("d").replace("M190,100", "")
    ].join(" ")
  )
  .attr("id", "full_shape") // let's rename this shape (as it's not the left edge anymore)
  .style("fill", "lightgray"); // and let's finally fill the shape (our goal!)

// Let's remove the initial sub-sections of the shape as they are not needed anymore:
topCurve.exit().remove();
curvedLine.exit().remove();
supportJunction.exit().remove();

/* draw points used */
svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.leftEdge)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'black');

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.topCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'blue');

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.bottomCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr('r', 3)
  .style('fill', 'red');

/* draw labels */
svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.leftEdge)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x - 16; })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y + 10; })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.topCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y - 8; })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; })
  .style('fill', 'blue');

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.supportJunction)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x + 16; })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y - 8; })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; })
  .style('fill', 'purple');

svg.selectAll('circles')
  .data(shape.bottomCurve)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x - 16; })
  .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y - 8; })
  .attr('dy', 1)
  .text(function(d) { return d.id; })
  .style('fill', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="svgContainer"></div>
```

And here is the section of interest:

```
var leftEdge = svg.select("#left_edge");
var topCurve = svg.select("#top_curve");
var supportJunction = svg.select("#support_junction");
var curvedLine = svg.select("#bottom_curve");

// Let's merge all paths together by replacing left edge's d attribute (path)
// with the concatenation of the different sub-paths:
leftEdge
  .attr(
    "d",
    leftEdge.attr("d") + " " +
    topCurve.attr("d").replace("M160,20", "") + " " +
    supportJunction.attr("d") + " " +
    curvedLine.attr("d").replace("M190,100", "")
  )
  .attr("id", "full_shape") // let's rename this shape (as it's not the left edge anymore)
  .style("fill", "lightgray"); // and let's finally fill the shape (our goal!)

// Let's remove the initial sub-sections of the shape as they are not needed anymore:
topCurve.exit().remove();
curvedLine.exit().remove();
supportJunction.exit().remove();
```

---

*Let's detail a bit more what we're actually doing:*

After giving an id to each sub-path when creating them (`.attr("id", "#left_edge")`), we can then easily select them and retrieve their `d` attributes produced by d3:

```
svg.select("#left_edge").attr("d")
svg.select("#top_curve").attr("d")
svg.select("#support_junction").attr("d")
svg.select("#bottom_curve").attr("d")
```

which gives us these 4 sub-paths:

```
M160,140L155.2777777777778,139.25C150.55555555555557,138.5,141.11111111111111,137,135.44444444444446,127C129.7777777777778,117,127.8888888888889,98.5,127.88888888888891,80C127.8888888888889,61.5,129.7777777777778,43,135.44444444444446,33C141.11111111111111,23,150.55555555555557,21.5,155.2777777777778,20.75L160,20
M160,20L158.95833333333334,26.166666666666668C157.91666666666666,32.333333333333336,155.83333333333334,44.666666666666664,160.83333333333334,51.333333333333336C165.83333333333334,58,177.91666666666666,59,183.95833333333334,59.5L190,60
M190,60L190,100
M190,100L183.95833333333334,100.5C177.91666666666666,101,165.83333333333334,102,160.83333333333334,108.66666666666667C155.83333333333334,115.33333333333333,157.91666666666666,127.66666666666667,158.95833333333334,133.83333333333334L160,140
```

With these svg sub-paths, we can now create a new path which is the concatenation of these 4 sub-paths by joining them with `" "`:

```
var wholeShapePath =
  [
    leftEdge.attr("d"),
    topCurve.attr("d").replace("M160,20", ""),
    supportJunction.attr("d"),
    curvedLine.attr("d").replace("M190,100", "")
  ].join(" ");
```

**Notice how I remove the "moveTo" `M` commands** (such as `M160,20`) from the beginning of sub-paths, as it has the effect of starting a new sub-path (which is why your concatenation didn't work).

With this new path representing the whole shape, we can now apply it by modifying one of the sub-paths to use the whole shape's path instead (and by the way filling the inner area!):

```
svg.select("#left_edge")
  .attr("d", wholeShapePath)
  .style("fill", "lightgray");
```

Without forgetting to discard the other sub-paths which are not usefull anymore:

```
topCurve.exit().remove();
curvedLine.exit().remove();
supportJunction.exit().remove();
```